# Understanding the difference between extending a class and importing a class

Tags: java, inheritance, import, extend, difference

I have seen several threads that define extending a class as a way for a personalized class to inherit the methods of the class that it is extended to.  When you import a class and create an instance of that class you have access to its methods, can someone please explain to me how extending a class to provide those methods to your own class is effectively different, in other words, the only difference I see is that when you import you create an instance of a standardized class, and when you extend you effectively turn your personalized class into the standardized class only with a different name.  I am aware I am wrong, but the answers I have read have failed to help me fundamentally understand the difference.

Comment: Small point: I think instead of "importing," the term you want is "composition." This may help you search for answers: there are *lots* of articles out there about the [difference between *inheritance* and *composition*](https://www.google.com/#q=difference+between+inheritance+and+composition) and about *is-a* vs. *has-a* relationships.

Comment: Basically you're asking the different between being something, and having/using something. A Banana *is* a Fruit (it extends Fruit). A Buyer buys and eats fruits.

Answer (score 8):

Importing and extending are two very different things.

#### Importing

Classes are organized in packages, which provide a namespace facility that avoids name conflicts. Importing allows you to use the class in your code without the namespace information.

Importing is optional. You never have to import anything if you always use the fully qualified name of the class, but that makes your code hard to read.

If you want to make a list of Calendar objects, for example, you either import `java.util.List`, `java.util.ArrayList` and `java.util.Calendar` and use:

```
List<Calendar> array = new ArrayList<>();
```

Or import nothing and use:

```
java.util.List<java.util.Calendar> array = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
```

Sometimes you have two classes with the same name in different packages. In that case, if you use both of them in your code you can't import both. You will have to refer to one of them by their fully qualified name. For example:

```
List<java.awt.List> array; // you have to import java.util.List, but can't also import java.awt.List
```

#### Extending

When you extend in Java you are saying that the subclass **is a type of** the original class. That's the most important aspect you have to be aware of when using `extends`. Is you say `Bus extends Vehicle` you are saying that `Bus` **is a** `Vehicle`. You not only inherit all the non-private methods and fields of the superclass, but also can use the subclass anywhere you could legally use the superclass. For example, if you have this method:

```
public park(Vehicle v) {
   v.drive();
   v.turn(Direction.LEFT);
   v.stop();
}
```

you could pass a `Bus` as an argument, because `Bus` is a `Vehicle`.

```
parkingLot.park(new Bus());
```

and the `drive()`, `turn()` and `stop()` methods will be called in the `Bus`. That is polymorphism.

Although you inherit methods, inheritance is not the best way to reuse code. Most of the time when you need to reuse code you can do it by using composition (making your class **have a** reference to another class, instead of **being** one). A `Car` shouldn't extend `Motor` because a car is not a motor, but it could *have* a motor and *delegate* a call to the motor's `turnOn()` method when the car's `drive()` method is called.

You can also have polymorphism without inheritance in Java using interfaces.

Answer (score 5):

To make a simple example (but bad :/ ). Lets say you have a Person class.

```
public Person 
{
    int age;
    string name;
}
```

Then you have different type of persons that inherit the Person class, eg.

```
public SoftwareDeveloper extends Person 
{
    string codingLanguage;
}
```

Now you can easily create a SoftwareDeveloper and use its attributes like this:

```
public static void main () 
{
    SoftwareDeveloper developer = new SoftwareDeveloper();
    System.print.out(developer.name);  
}
```

If you would "import" instead, you would have to create an instance of Person in SoftwareDevelopers constructor and make it public. So your code would be to access the attribute:

```
public SoftwareDeveloper
{
    public Person person;
    string codingLanguage;

    public SoftwareDeveloper(){
         person = new Person();
    }
}

public static void main () 
{
    SoftwareDeveloper developer = new SoftwareDeveloper();
    System.print.out(developer.person.name);  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in small scale your reasoning works fine but the idea of extending is that your class inherits all the methods of the extended class.

But if you start with a simple idea or program and want to expand it massively the use of instantiating all the classes you need becomes much more consuming. On even a simple idea the increase in imports can explode.

Example:

Animal - warm blooded - biped - human

Animal - warm blooded - quadruped - feline - cougar - panther

Now you want to have your panther have all the methods of the 5 classes its built apoun.
So that 5 imports and objects you have to manipulate to get to all the methods you want to access. But if all these are extending each other you just have direct access to the methods. And this is a simple example now imagine a huge accounting program.

So point I trying to make....I think...Is that its much more prevalent and easier to understand the usefulness in extending classes when you look at it in the large scale.

Hope this helps or makes as much sense as it does to me.

Answer (score 0):

Extending a class means that your class is "inheriting" the methods of the standard class; in other words, you are taking an existing class and building your class on top of it.  That is how Java manages all objects (i.e. every class that you create actually extends the default Object class).  When you import a class, on the other hand, you have access to all its functionality, but you cannot build on top of it as you could with inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with *importing* a class.  You `import` a class in order to use it in another class, if that class is in another package.  It's really just a shortcut that's saying when you see a class called `X` used, what I really mean if `com.somepackage.X`.

Extending is taking a class and using it as a base for a new class.  There's alsorts of reasons to do this (well beyond the scope of an answer here) but the important thing is that you inherit the behaviour of the class you are extending and have the choice of whether or not to override that behaviour or add additional behaviour.

For good example of classes being extended, look at the Collection API in [java.util](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) where you can see [java.util.AbstractList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) is extended to ultimately create two different types of list, each with different characteristics - [java.util.ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) and [java.util.LinkedList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

Answer (score 0):

Lets look on an example.

We have class which provide an update function to database and containing a String variable.

```
public class DBupdate {
public String StrVar = "Hello";
    ...
    public void doUpdate(String expression) {
        try {
            connect();
            runExp(expression);
            disconnect();
        } catch ...
    }
}
```

If you import it. You will do something like

```
log(new DBupdate.StrVar);
String myExp = "UPDATE ..."; // SQL
new DBupdate.doUpdate(myExp);
```

If you extend.

```
log(StrVar);
String myExp = "UPDATE ..."; // SQL
doUpdate(myExp);
```

doUpdate() function and StrVar became part of your new class. So all functions and variables (which are public or protected) are part of your new class (inherited).

Example for usefull import (and not extend/inherit) is log4j. It is doing work like writing to console and into a file. But you want just to use it "log" function and no speacial functions it is using for its work.

Example for usefull inherit is java.lang.Thread. If you class became a thread it can be treated as a Thread and will be splitted to run parallel, if you use java.lang.Thread function "start()". (Override run() method to do so some stuff...)

Answer (score 0):

At the very simplest case it can be said that, Import Statement improves readability and reduces the length of the code.

In java we implement dynamic loading, language import statement no class file is loaded at the time of import statement, when ever we are suing a class, at the time of only the corresponding .calss file will be loaded.

Extends-
In Java, when we wish to extend the usefulness of a class, we can create a new class that inherits the attributes and methods of another. We don't need a copy of the original source code (as is the case with many other languages) to extend the usefulness of a library. We simply need a compiled '.class' file, from which we can create a new enhancement. I could not find a better way to explain so just refer this link..(source -http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/java104/java104.html)